# Xcode "OmniSearch" in autocomplete

Tags: xcode, xcode5

In other IDEs during code complete, I could type any char/word inside the method (doesn't have to be in the order it apears) and it will filter out those methods.

So far, it seems like in Xcode, I'll have to type out the name of the method from beginning to end in order, else the autocomplete popup disappears.

Is there any way to get this "omnisearch" feature in Xcode?

Comment: Do you mean like you have a variable or method named, say, "fooBarBaz" and when you type "Bar" it shows up in the list? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @user1118321 Exactly like that.

Comment: I don't believe the auto-complete does that. Oddly, the Open Quickly popup window, does though. I don't know why there's a discrepancy there.

Comment: @user1118321 How do I access the Open Quickly popup window?

Comment: You can either select it from the "File" menu, or use the key binding for it. I believe the default key binding is Cmd-Shift-O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode's auto complete does not support that.